# Tagging VLAN1 on a switch

Tags: networking, switch, vlan

I have a Nortel switch which dates back to 2006. It has an egress tagging function which I think tags all VLANs including native VLAN1.

This is my scenario: I plugged my laptop into that port which is egress tagged and it got connected. My question is, if I tag all VLANs on the trunk port including VLAN1, will my laptop still connect to VLAN1 no matter what, as it is the default VLAN, or the connection will be dropped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have a normal connection with the default VLAN (PVID). If you want to use the additional (trunked) VLAN's, you have to configure your computer to use them. If not, all frames tagged with a 802.1q tag will be dropped by the NIC or the kernel (depending on OS/drivers).

Comment: Hey mtak thanks for your reply... if i understood you right... if I tag the native vlan1 802.1q and i connect a laptop to that port it will still connect? even though it is tagged?? but for other vlans that are not the default vlan i will have to add the vlan id to my nic to be able to connect to that vlan?

Comment: By definition, the native VLAN is not tagged (it is untagged, that's why it's *native*). You will still be able to connect. For tagged VLAN's (non native) you will need to take extra steps to use those VLAN's. The steps involved are highly dependent on your system configuration.

Comment: ok now i understand why the laptop still workds if i tag vlan 1 but can you explain why when i connect another device like a NAS for example with a fixed ip address on it (192.168.x.x) it won't connect to vlan1?